# woocomerce is serving OR Relation instead of AND on taxonomy product_tag

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to use URL query to filter my products but when I do this, I only want products that are jeans and are red. For example how can I break the `OR` relation to an `AND` relation?

This is my example URL:
`?product_tag[0]=jeans&product_tag[1]=red`

I'm using Woocomerce.

Comment: Wilmar, technically WooCommerce questions are off topic, but you can easily edit your question to be just WordPress specific by leaving out the fact that this is for Woo and just changing it so that you're asking about querying tags. :-)
To assist, the & in the URL parameters isn't the same as 'AND' in a query, you do not need to change this if that's what you're asking. When you're running a `WP_Query` you'll set the relation to `AND` in the actual `tax_query`.  Include your `WP_Query` code and I'll do what I can to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is how i added AND filter on product tags 
 
   function product_tag_and_filter( $query ) {
    
        if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){
            return;
        }
        if(is_product_category()){
    
        $tax_query = array();
    
        // add meta_query elements
        if( !empty( get_query_var( 'product_tag' ) ) ){
            foreach(get_query_var( 'product_tag' ) as $val){
            $tax_query[] = array(  'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'field' => 'slug',  'terms' => $val , 'compare' => '=' );
            }
     
        }
    
    
    
        if( count( $tax_query ) > 1 ){
            $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
        }
    
        if( count( $tax_query ) > 0 ){
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'product_tag_and_filter', 1 );
```